# how to find dependency related to specific class

Tags: class, dependencies, find

I am going to use Package Manager class in my code, but in android studio it is not recognizable  class for it . I want to add dependency for it , but I do not know that how to search dependency related to this class on google so that I can easily find it and  can add it to graddle.build file.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for classnames in MavenCentral:

https://search.maven.org/

with `c:yourClassName`